# Given a state and a city with the same name how to look just for the city with google maps API?

Tags: google-maps

For instance, take Québec. It is both a province and a city. Using google maps API with the query string of 'Québec' yields the province as the result. What should I query for if I want just the city?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be as specific as possible. Generally the geocoder will find a country name before a province, a province before a city, and so on.

For Quebec, use either `Quebec City` (which isn't the province) or `Quebec, Quebec` (specifying the city within the province). The tiles show "Quebec City" for the name of the city, too.

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried it, but it may be "types":["locality"] when building your geocode query.  From [The Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Types).  I'm not a javascript coder normally so I am not sure what the syntax would look like but it may help you to narrow down results to just the city.